# Django models and querysets

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I would like to get your help because I'm blocked in my Django web application.

I have two classes in my model :

```
class Document(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=25, verbose_name=_('code'), unique=True, null=False, blank=False, default='')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=512, verbose_name=_('document title'))

class Download(models.Model):
    email = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name=_('e-mail'), null=False)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, verbose_name=_('country'), related_name='download')
    doc = models.ForeignKey(Document, verbose_name=_('Document'), null=True)
    token = models.CharField(max_length=40, verbose_name=_('download token'), unique=True, null=False)
    expiration_date = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name=_('expiration date'), null=False)
```

As you can see, `Download` class is bounded to `Document` class thanks to `ForeignKey`.

Now, in my views.py, I have this :

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    email = form.cleaned_data['email']
    country = form.cleaned_data['country']

    for checkbox in self.request.GET.getlist('DocumentChoice'):
        document = Document.objects.get(code=checkbox)
        token = self.gen_token(email)

        now = timezone.now()
        expiration = now + settings.DOWNLOAD_VALIDITY
        Download.objects.create(email=email, country=country, doc_id=checkbox, token=token, expiration_date=expiration)

    return super(HomeView, self).form_valid(form)
```

**What I would like to do:**

In this line : `Download.objects.create(email=email, country=country, doc_id=checkbox, token=token, expiration_date=expiration)`

I would like to set`document.code = checkbox` but I don't overcome to find the good way to do that. `checbox` corresponds to a list of code from `document`model.

I tried `doc_code`, `doc_id_code` ... but I don't find the good syntax to make reference to `document.code` from `download` class.

Thank you

Comment: But here `document.code` is already set to `checkbox`, you **fetch** a document with that `code`, tat is what `Document.objects.get(code=checkbox)` is doing.

Comment: the code is already there in the table thus only you are getting it by get, why do you need to save again? and no you cannot do that inside the Download model create

Comment: I just have to write this `Download.objects.create(email=email, country=country, doc_id=document.id, token=token, expiration_date=expiration)` ?

Comment: you can directly assign object Download.objects.create(email=email, country=country, doc=document, token=token, expiration_date=expiration)